# How to start flask application with socket.io

Tags: flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a flask application running over Gunicorn WSGI HTTP Server. My flask version is 0.10.1. A simple version of my app initialization is given below. In real app, it does many things than this.

```
import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!
```

I run the app with the shell script.

```
exec gunicorn --timeout 300 -c "$ROOT"/deploy/gunicorn.conf.py deploy:app "$@"
```

The configuration file gunicorn.conf.py is given below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
bind = "127.0.0.1:18000"
workers = min(4, multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1)
preload = True
worker_class = "gevent"
loglevel = "warning"
```

This is all working fine so far. Now, I am implementing a socket feature in one of my application page. The socket will only be used in that specific page and not when I browse to other pages. I am using Flask_socketio for the server part and socket.io in the client side.

As per the link [socket.io with flask](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I need to run app using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Now my confusion is, do I need to wrap my whole app object in socketio and start it using socketio.run(app). Isn't there any other way where I can initialize socket only for that page. Also I would like to know what would be the impact if I use socketio.run(app) from now on.

Comment: Did you see the section of the docs that discusses how to run with gunicorn? https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gunicorn-web-server